# Load modal on click

Tags: javascript

I want to load modal automatically on page load and the modal would close and reopen onclick. I have put following command to automatically load modal `modal.open();` This loaded my modal automatically on page load. Later I have used following to close the modal on button click: `function onClick() { if (modal.isOpen) {close(); } }` This one is working too. But now, I want to load the modal again by clicking the button which is not working.
When I am placing `openButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  modal.open();
});` instead of `modal.open();` the modal is loading on every alternative click and closing on other clicks. But in this scenario, I am not getting automatically loading of modal on page load.

Comment: Please post all of the relevant code.

Comment: `close()` is working? That would refer to `window.close`, not `modal.close`, though. Calling it would fail with a warning like “Scripts can’t close windows that weren’t opened by the user” in the console.

Comment: How are you attempting to open the modal again by clicking the button?

Comment: data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal' data-backdrop='static' data-keyboard='false'

Comment: Please show us the entire code so we're not having to piece together what you are trying to do. It doesn't make sense at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to answer the best I can without seeing your functions.

```
function onClick() {
    if(modal.isOpen) { 
        close(); 
    } else {
      modal.open(); // you just need to call the same function you called when opening the page.
    }
}
```

Comment: This the most basic thing I have tried but is not working here.

Comment: @VikasPrasad Have you tried `modal.close();` instead of `close();` as I mentioned in my comment?

Comment: the close(); is working fine. I am asking for opening the modal again.